# Why didn't Olivia Rodrigo receive any nominations for 2021 Billboard Music Awards?

Tags: award, billboard

As we know Olivia Rodrigo released her newest single *Driver's license* on January 8th, 2021; and it became very popular on Billboard Hot 100 so that it remained 1st on the list for 8 consecutive weeks.

First of all, the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2021_Billboard_Music_Awards) page says:

> Nominees for Top Hot 100 Artist, Top Latin Male Artist, and Top Rap Female Artist were announced on April 28, 2021. The full list of nominations were presented on April 29, 2021. The Weeknd is the most nominated artist, earning sixteen nominations.

P.S 1: There is a little grammar error in the Wikipedia quoted text.

P.S 2: The announcement of nominations is after the release date of the Driver's license.

There are so many categories in the awards including *Top Streaming Song Artist*, *Top Song Sales Artist*, *Top Radio Song Artist*, and *Top Social Artist (fan-voted)*, which Rodrigo could be in all of them; because being first on the list for eight weeks results in it stream very much, be sold very much, and beloved by fans very much; or even vice-versa. She could also be in *Top Hot 100 Artist* because it was the Hot 100 list which the song remained at the top of it for eight consecutive weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awards are always a bit subjective, even for a data-driven business like the music charts.

If she didn't make it onto the fan-voted nominations, it's because the fans didn't vote for her (in enough numbers). For the other categories, you'll notice she was up against some well established superstars.

As a new artist who just debuted earlier this year, she may not have had enough time to make her mark on the nominators. If she has another hit single between now and next year's nominations, look for her in the Best New Artist category then...